# Ember event for best discarding changes between same Route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an Ember list and an edit form.
Each time the selected item of the list changes the edit form discards any changes and loads new model.

My problem is that there is no way to discard changes because the deactivate event does NOT fire.

For example going from `url/favs/123/edit` to `url/favs/456/edit` deactivate (and exit) event does NOT fire. So there is no way to properly discard any changes.

Here is the part of my code I am referring to:

```js
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('favs', { path: '/favs' }, function() {
        this.route('new');
        this.route('edit', { path: ':fav_id/edit' })
    });
});

[...]

App.FavsEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    deactivate: function() {
        var model = this.get('currentModel');
        if(model && model.get('isDirty')) {
            model.get('transaction').rollback();
        }
    },

    model: function(params) {
        return App.Fav.find(params.fav_id);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using the willTransition route action. It currently appears to be advertised as the solution in the Ember Guide:

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/

Aside from being in the public API, this approach has the advantage that you can prompt the user to confirm if they actually want to abandon the change, nullifying the transition if they say no.

For example:

```
App.FavsEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  ...
  actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      controller = this.controllerFor('fav');
      if (controller.get('isDirty') &&
          !confirm("Are you sure you want to abandon progress?")) {
        transition.abort();
        return false;
      } else {
        controller.get("content").rollback();
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The deactivate hook is just executed when the route is left completely. Therefore i would suggest to overwrite the contextDidChange function of your Route. Here is an excerpt from the Ember Source:

```
Ember.Route = Ember.Object.extend({
    /**
    @private

    Called when the context is changed by router.js.
  */
  contextDidChange: function() {
    this.currentModel = this.context;
  }
});
```

I would suggest to do this:

```
App.FavsEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    deactivate: function() {
        this.doRollback();
    },
    contextDidChange: function() {
        this.doRollback();
        this._super();
    },
    doRollback: function(){
        var model = this.get('currentModel');
        if(model && model.get('isDirty')) {
            model.get('transaction').rollback();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ember is young. Works like a charm but doRollback code might be better like this

Comment: var controller = this.controller,
        content = (controller? controller.get('content'): null);
  
  if(content && content.get('isDirty')) {
  
          content.get('transaction').rollback();
    }

Comment: Now if only there was an intermediate state for presenting an HTML dialog to ask user would be awesome. Still this is more than enough :)

Comment: tip for more: http://darthdeus.github.com/blog/2013/02/08/router-request-lifecycle/

Comment: What should the intermediate dialog do? Asking if he really wants to drop changes, or what?

Comment: yep: You have unsaved changes. Delete?/Cancel

Comment: I notice contextDidChange() is a private method in the API. I think willTransition action does more or less the the same thing though.

Comment: would be great to create a type of Router with that behavior :) worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Ember 2.2 the correct code (in route) is:

```
actions: {
  saveScene: function (scene) {
    var _that = this;

    scene.save().then(function (response) {
      // on saveScene action, go to list route
      _that.transitionTo('scenes');
    });
  },

  willTransition: function (transition) {
    // on transition, if model has unsaved changes, revert them
    var model = this.controller.get('model');
    if (model && model.get('hasDirtyAttributes')) {
      model.rollbackAttributes();
    }
  }
}
```